# How can I change default user on Ubuntu Windows?

Tags: windows-10, users, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Whenever I click on the Ubuntu app in the start menu I'm logged in as root. Is there any way I can set the default user to be the user I created?

Comment: That's the trick. Thanks @Kulfy

Answer (score 5):

To change the default user, open command prompt with administrator privileges and run

```
ubuntu config --default-user username
```

You can replace `ubuntu` with the release you are using, for example, `ubuntu1604` and `ubuntu1804`.

Comment: Currently ubuntu2004.

Comment: You know, this seems like a simple enough question with a simple enough answer, but it just wouldn't work for me...until I set "path=%path%;C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps", where <USERNAME> is my user profile folder name. I have 18.04.5 LTS. Prior to this, the ubuntu and ubuntu1804 commands wouldn't work because they simply weren't in the path for my machine.