# How do I change the default user that signs in on WSL?

Tags: permissions, users, windows-subsystem-for-linux, default, user-management

I'm running Ubuntu terminal on windows with WSL, Every time I launch the terminal it signs me in as the root user. I've created a new user and given them root privileges so that I can code easier. How do I change the default user that gets signed in?

This is what I see when I launch:

[image: This is what I see when I launch]

After running `su shayc` I can get to my user, but how do I avoid doing this
every time?

**UPDATE: **
I've tried setting a default user in /etc/wsl.conf

[image: This is the wsl.conf file]

Note: also I am not able to run WSL commands

[image: wsl not found]

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1209881/1222991) may be the one you’re looking for 

Answer (score 8):

A few things to look at here.  First, when you ran Ubuntu for the first time after installing on WSL, it *should* have gone through a "configuration" step where it asked you to create a username and password.  This user would be the "default user" that *should* be used when running.  If the instance is running with "root" as the default user, then that could signal an error in the configuration (and from the comments, this appears to be what happened).

That's not a huge deal, honestly.  You've done the right thing in creating a new user.  Just that it *shouldn't* have been necessary.

As for setting that new user as default, there are at least two possible paths:

---

##### Option 1: `wsl.conf`

The current [Microsoft recommended](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/manage#user) way is to create a `/etc/wsl.conf` in the instance with the following setting:

```
[user]
default=username
```

Changing, of course, username to be your default username.

Exit your instance, issue a `wsl --terminate Ubuntu` (assuming your instance name is "Ubuntu", which you can confirm with `wsl -l -v`) or `wsl --shutdown` (from PowerShell or CMD), and restart.

---

##### Option 2: "Reset" the instance back to the configuration stage

*Note that this is a destructive operation*.  If you don't have any work inside the instance that you can't recover easily, then you can easily reset the instance back to the initial state.  This is because WSL leaves the original rootfs for any distribution a hidden directory under `C:\ProgramData`.

You can always back up the old instance before doing this "just in case".  The commands (again, all from PowerShell or CMD) should look something like:

```
wsl --export Ubuntu "2021-11-21 Ubuntu WSL Backup.tar"
```

Then (and this is the **destructive** part):

```
wsl --unregister Ubuntu
```

Then rerun the "App" with `ubuntu.exe` (or, if you installed a version-specific app from the Store, it may be `ubuntu2004.exe`).

At that point, the configuration step will re-run, asking for the default username and password.

Comment: Thank you so much, and yeah my pc decided to restart when I was setting that up, okay so where exactly does this file go? (Where is /etc) or do I just use that path from the root directory?

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't work.. Ive updated Post

Comment: The `wsl` command is typically run from *outside* the WSL instance -- From PowerShell or CMD.  I've updated my answer to make that more clear.  The `/etc/wsl.conf` won't take effect until you really do terminate it, so that's hopefully why you aren't seeing the new user.  If you *do* need to run the `wsl` command from inside Ubuntu, use `wsl.exe`, since it's a Windows executable.

Comment: @Shayc20 Sorry, I forgot to tag you in my response yesterday, so you may not have been notified.

Answer (score 4):

Simply open a command prompt and run:

```
ubuntu2204 config --default-user <username>
```

... where `ubuntu2204` can be replaced with your specific WSL distribution and username is the profile you want to become default