# Ubuntu (on Windows) only root user available

Tags: root

I have installed Ubuntu on Windows, but somehow when I start it, only the root user is available, if I type "EXIT" it closes the terminal.

Comment: That should be normal. What is stopping you from creating a user if you want one? (the command is `adduser` iirc) :-) On and be careful: Linux is case-sensitive ;) so it is probably "exit".

Comment: See [How do I change the default user that signs in on WSL?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1376711/how-do-i-change-the-default-user-that-signs-in-on-wsl)